# How do you force a templatization to match a base class?

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

I have a template function which is explicitly instantiated for `Base` class, but not for `Derived` class.  How can I force the uses that pass a `Derived` class (or other derived classes) to match against the `Base` class?

Header file:

```
class Base {
};
class Derived : public Base {
};
class Derived2 : public Base {
};

template <typename Example> void function(Example &arg);
```

Implementation file:

```
// Explicitly instantiate Base class:
template void function<Base>(Base &arg);

// Define the template function:
template <typename Example> void function(Example &arg) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Because I have not explicitly instantiated function for `Derived` or `Derived2`, I get undefined references, however, I would like to bind against the `Base` class which is explicitly defined.

How can I force the template to resolve to the Base class for all objects derived from Base using C++-03?

Can I do it somehow with a specialization of the `Derived` class to the `Base` class definition?

Comment: Instead of using a template, why not using a set of overloaded functions? That way the compiler knows which set is available and can choose accordingly. If you want to share implementation, have those functions forward to a template.

Comment: If the argument to `function` should always be `Base&`, then `function` should not use a template parameter in its parameter list, and probably should not be a template at all.

Comment: @Sjoerd because there are around 20 overloadings, I'd rather not have those in the header file and instead move them to the implementation as explicit instantiations and further, I now only have the definition showing up once instead of twenty times for each overloading.

Comment: You can always cast the `arg` to a `(Base&)derived` when you call the function... :)

Comment: @Alex I'd prefer to not do this at the caller as that seems messy to me.  I'd like to tell compiler in the header file to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
template <> void function(Derived &arg)
{
     function<Base>( arg );
}
```

EDIT: You can also do this with function overloading, as **aschepler** has suggested:

```
void function(Derived &arg)
{
     function<Base>( arg );
}
```

It's conceptually the same, although, I agree, slightly better :)

Comment: Prefer function overloading to explicit specialization of a function template: `inline void function(Derived& arg) { function<Base>(arg); }`

Comment: @aschepler I think the compiler would match the template definition before matching the overloading you give here.

Comment: When a non-template function and a function template specialization have the same function type, overload resolution always picks the non-template.